# Problema con código formulario + ComboBox + Tabla en PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hola estoy haciendo un sitio en PHP el cual me está dando problemas, el código que tengo es un formulario, el cual el usuario selecciona un nombre y una ruta. Les dejo una imagen de como se ve hasta el momento.
[image: Sitio del Formulario - Imagen 1]

Luego de seleccionar un nombre y una ruta. El formulario me envía a otra página, como muestra el siguiente ejemplo:

[image: Sitio Resultado - Imagen 2]

Como se puede ver:

- Los datos están repetidos y fuera de posición.
- Los datos no concuerdan con lo buscado, únicamente el 1er registro de ese ejemplo concuerda con los datos solicitados.

Para más detalles dejaré el codigo de mi sitio.

Formulario de las listas desplegables

(La tabla de la Imagen 1 no pertenece al formulario de las listas desplegables).

```
<form method="POST" action="ResultadoEjecucion.php" name="form1">
    <table width="1000" style="margin-left: 2cm;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="125" class="Verde_tit">
            <!--Este es un llamado a una función que llena el combobox-->
            Usuarios:&nbsp;<? echo (ObtenUsuariosEjecucion($link,$userId));?>               
            </td>

            <td width="125" class="Verde_tit">
            <!--Lo mismo pero para la ruta-->
                Ruta:&nbsp;<? echo (ObtenRutaEjecucion($link,$RutasE))?>            
            </td>

            <td>
                <input class="bot_buscar1" type="submit" name="Submit" value="" id="Submit">
            </td>                           
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Este es el código de las funciones que llenan las listas desplegables:

```
function ObtenRutaEjecucion($conn, $cual)
{
  $query=" select Items.id_ruta
        from ruta_actual as ruta 
        inner join usuarios AS Us ON Us.id_usuario = id_ruta
        inner join  items_tracking AS Items ON Items.id_ruta = ruta.id_ruta
        inner join  movil AS M ON M.id_usuario = Items.id_usuario

        where
        ruta.nro_items_ingresados = 1

        group by Items.imei, Nombres, Items.id_ruta
        order by Items.id_ruta";

  $result=mysql_query($query, $conn);
  echo("<select name='RutasE' id='RutasE'>\n");
  echo("<option value=0>--- ---</option>\n");


  while($result && ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))) {
            echo ("<option value=".$row[0]);
            if ($row[0]==$cual) {
                    echo (" selected ");
            }
            echo (">\n");
            echo ("$row[0]");
            echo ("</option>\n");
    }
    echo ("</select>\n");
```

}

```
function ObtenUsuariosEjecucion($conn, $cual)
{
  $query="
  select Items.imei, Us.Nombres, Items.id_ruta, SUM( ruta.nro_items ), 
  SUM(ruta.nro_items_ingresados ), 
  (CONCAT(((SUM(ruta.nro_items_ingresados ) ) *100) DIV 
  (select SUM(ruta.nro_items )), '', '%')), (SUM(ruta.nro_items ) - 
  SUM( ruta.nro_items_ingresados ) ), 

  count( * )

  from ruta_actual AS ruta

  inner join usuarios AS Us ON Us.id_usuario = id_ruta
  inner join items_tracking AS Items ON Items.id_ruta = ruta.id_ruta
  inner join movil AS M ON M.id_usuario = Items.id_usuario

  where ruta.nro_items_ingresados =1

  group by Items.imei, Nombres, Items.id_ruta
  order by Items.id_ruta ";

  $result = mysql_query($query, $conn);
  echo("<select name='userId' id='userId'>\n");
  echo ("<option value=0>--- SELECCIONE --- </option>\n");

  while($result && ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))) {
            echo ("<option value=".$row[1]);
            if ($row[1]==$cual) {
                    echo (" selected ");
            }
            echo (">\n");
            echo ($row[1]);
            echo ("</option>\n");
    }
    echo ("</select>\n");

}
```

Con esas funciones yo sé que no hay drama, pero las puse para que se entienda mejor mi problema.

Y el siguiente código es el de la pagina de recepción de los parámetros enviados por el formulario.

```
<?php
    /*Estas primeras lineas hasta el QUERY es un codigo que utilizo 
    para el diseño de la cabecera del sitio y de la conexión con la Base
    de Datos*/  
    include ("../php/cabecera.php");
    include ("../php/util.php");
    include ("../php/sql.php");

    $link = myinit();
    $usuario = $_SESSION['usuariocookie'];

    /*Y este QUERY es el que llena la tabla al momento de cargar el 
    formulario antes de enviar los datos, corresponde a la Imagen 1 que 
    muestro en esta pregunta.

    Lo puse tambien en esta pagina de recepción de los datos pensando que me 
    funcionaría después de haber enviado el formulario en la pagina  
    principal*/

    $query="SELECT Items.imei, Us.Nombres, Items.id_ruta,
    SUM( ruta.nro_items ), SUM( ruta.nro_items_ingresados ), 
    (CONCAT(((SUM( ruta.nro_items_ingresados))*100) DIV 
    (SELECT SUM( ruta.nro_items)),'','%')), 

    (SUM( ruta.nro_items ) - SUM( ruta.nro_items_ingresados ) ), 

    COUNT( * )

    FROM ruta_actual AS ruta
    INNER JOIN usuarios AS Us ON Us.id_usuario = id_ruta
    INNER JOIN items_tracking AS Items ON Items.id_ruta = ruta.id_ruta
    INNER JOIN movil AS M ON M.id_usuario = Items.id_usuario
    WHERE ruta.nro_items_ingresados =1
    GROUP BY Items.imei, Nombres, Items.id_ruta, ruta.id_ruta
    ORDER BY Items.id_ruta";

    $result=mysql_query($query,$link);

    /*Estas 2 variables son las que rescatan el valor de los combobox 
    que se seleccionaron respectivamente*/  
    $ValorUser = $_POST['userId'];
    $ValorRuta=$_POST['RutasE'];

    /*Las cuales utilizo para mostrar en la tabla de este mismo sitio
    de recepción, al final de todo este código*/


?>

<table width="1000" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="Verde_tit">SEGUIMIENTO EJECUCIONES</td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" valign="top">
                    <a href="menu.php" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image50','','../images/bot_volver_on.jpg',1)">
                        <img name="Image50" border="0" src="../images/bot_volver_off.jpg" width="80" height="25">
                    </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </td>

                <td width="93" align="right" valign="top">
                    <a "resultado_excel.php<? echo($cadena_excel)?>" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image51','','../images/bot_excel_on.jpg',1)">
                        <img name="Image51" border="0" src="../images/bot_excel_off.jpg" width="60" height="25">
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table width="1000" style="margin-left: 2cm;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="125" class="Verde_tit">
                                Usuarios:&nbsp;<? echo (ObtenUsuariosEjecucion($link,$userId));?>

                            </td>

                            <td width="125" class="Verde_tit">
                                ;Ruta:&nbsp;<? echo (ObtenRutaEjecucion($link,$RutasE))?>

                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <input class="bot_buscar1" type="submit" name="Submit" value="" id="Submit">
                            </td>                           
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr> 
                <td>
                    <table width="703" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#136D86" style="margin-left: 3cm;">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="40" align="center" style="color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">IMEI</td>
                            <td width="82" align="center" style="color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">USUARIO</td>
                            <td width="30" align="center" style="color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">RUTA</td>
                            <td width="39" align="center" style="color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">BIPS</td>
                            <td width="70" align="center" style="color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">BIPS EJECUTADOS</td>
                            <td width="80" align="center" style="color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">EFICACIA - %</td>
                            <td width="50" align="center" style="color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">NO EJECUTADOS</td>
                            <td width="80" align="center" style="color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">TOTAL EJECUTADOS</td>
                       </tr>
               </table>
          </td>
     </tr>
<?php

while($result && ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))) {


if ($row[10] == 0)
{
    $cod_suc = $row[6];
}
else
{
    $cod_suc = $row[10];        
}

?>
                  <tr>
                      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="30" class="Verde_01" align="center" style="font-size: 10px;"><? echo($row[0])?></td>
                      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="30" class="Verde_01" align="center" style="font-size: 10px;"><? echo"$ValorUser"?></td>
                      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="30" class="Verde_01" align="center" style="font-size: 10px;"><? echo"$ValorRuta"?></td>
                      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="30" class="Verde_01" align="center" style="font-size: 10px;"><? echo($row[3])?></td>
                      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="30" class="Verde_01" align="center" style="font-size: 10px;"><? echo($row[4])?></td>    
                      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="30" class="Verde_01" align="center" style="font-size: 10px;"><? echo($row[5])?></td>
                      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="30" class="Verde_01" align="center" style="font-size: 10px;"><? echo($row[6])?></td>
                      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="30" class="Verde_01" align="center" style="font-size: 10px;"><? echo($row[7])?></td>
                </tr>
<? } ?>
</table>
```

Bueno ya aclarado todo, el problema es que ¿Cómo le hago para rescatar correctamente los datos de los combobox? Y que salgan en las columnas y filas de la tabla del sitio que los recepciona según como corresponden

Como por ejemplo, para el ejemplo ya mencionado en la Imagen 2, la tabla debe tener los siguientes datos.

- IMEI = 358126071590666
- Usuario = Eduardo
- Ruta = 1
- Bips = 399
- Bips Ejecutados= 361
- Eficacia= 90%
- No ejecutados= 38
- Total Ejecutados= 361

En orden desde IMEI hasta Total Ejecutados; y no repetidos como mostraba la 2da imagen, además de que la ruta o el nombre no concuerden entre sí con el registro de la base de datos, arroje un error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno lo más obvio es que los querys están mal ya que no tienes ningún where que limite los datos que te traigas con respecto a los select que tienes en el formulario, cuando haces el submit a ResultadoEjecucion.php así como obtienes:

```
$usuario = $_SESSION['usuariocookie'];
```

en tu otro archivo (no se si es el mismo), también puedes obtener el propio formulario con:

```
$_POST[];
```

que es un arreglo con dichos datos, ejemplo:

```
$rutasE = $_POST['RutasE'];
```

Te debería dar la opción seleccionada, ya luego con eso lo concatenas con los querys en los wheres correspondiente.

**PD**: te recomiendo que leas sobre PDO y también sobre sql injection ya que así como estás haciendo eso estás dejando una vulnerabilidad muy grande.

Saludos!

Comment: Ok ya veo voy a revisarlo mas a fondo mi código